# Anything written after index.php?page= loads website not causing 404 error

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have dynamic website based on HTML with PHP. I use index.php as layout file.
To load a subpage (ex. contact or news) i use url index.php?page=contact or index.php?page=news. That works without problem.

Problem is when user write anything after index.php?page= (index.php?page=anything). This should execute 404 error but loads website without content (only layout file). How to manage that?

I use .htaccess to make friendly links, so all my urls looks like http://mywebsite.com/contat instead of http://mywebsite.com/index.php?page=contact.

Code fragment for index.php:

```
<div id="links">
<hr class="line" size="1">
<a class="link1" href="/news">NEWS</a>
<a class="link1" href="/technical-info">TECHNICAL INFO</a>
<a class="link1" href="/entry-system">ENTRY SYSTEM</a>
<a class="link1" href="/starting-list">STARTING LIST</a>
<a class="link1" href="/results">RESULTS</a>
<a class="link1" href="/contact">CONTACT</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
<hr class="line" size="1">
<div style="margin-left: 35px; margin-right: 35px;">
<?php
if(empty($_GET['page']) or $_GET['page']=='news'){
include("news.php");
}
if($_GET['page']=="technical-info"){
include("technical-info.php");
}
if($_GET['page']=="entry-system"){
include("entry-system.php");
}
if($_GET['page']=="starting-list"){
include("starting-list.php");
}
if($_GET['page']=="contact"){
include("contact.php");
}
if($_GET['page']=="results"){
include("results.php");
}
if($_GET['page']=="add-entry"){
include("entrysystem/add-entry.php");
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

.htaccess code:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(news)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(technical-info)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(entry-system)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(starting-list)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(results)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(add-entry)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I see no reason here for your code to return a 404 HTTP code.

Comment: The problem is that i want 404 HTTP code after user will write anything after "?page=".
Now it just loads website without content.
For examplele indexp.php?page=fdjhfjew98efjshf will still work and load website not causing 404 HTTP error. Only defined parameters should work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace if blocks with elseif blocks and at last add an else condition. So it should look like this:

---

```
If($_GET['page']=='blah'){
       .....
}elseif($_GET['page']=='foo'){
       ....
}elseif($_GET['page']=='another-page'){
       ....
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    include("your_custom_404_page.php");
}
```

---

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /some/file.php:1) in /some/file.php on line 23

Comment: Add ob_start()  (php function) at the beginning of the php file